# C++ diff is a non-class

Tags: c++, class, std

This is my main function

```
#include <iostream>
#include "functions.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    functions LPG;
    LPG.diff();
    return 0;
}
```

Ubuntu says this file(main.cpp) has an error.

```
// functions.h
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
class functions{
    public:
    void diff(int error);
};
```

```
// functions.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "functions.h"

using namespace std;

`functions::diff(int error){
    error = error;
    void diff2(){
        error = 0;
        cout << "Joe Mama Testing 123";
        void easy(){
            cout << "Joe Mama Again"
        }
    }
}
```

Ubuntu says that diff is a non function
Someone please help me and this is not a joke I put joe mama because I want to test the class.
Please help me as soon a possible.

Comment: you cannot define functions within functions. What is that `diff2` and `easy` supposed to be good for?

Comment: What's the observable output you want to see on your screen? You appear to have some misconceptions about C++ and there's likely a simple way to achieve what you want to see.

Comment: You have a backtick before the definition ```diff```.

Comment: `diff` expects a parameter but you don't give it one.

Comment: `diff` is also missing the return type in the definition.

Answer (score 0):

You can declare `diff2` as a lambda function. That would allow you to have a function within a function.

```
void functions::diff(int error) {
    error = error;

    auto diff2 = [&error](void) {
      error = 0;
      cout << "Joe mama testing 123";

      auto easy = [](void) {
        cout << "Joe mama again";
      };

      easy();
    };

    diff2();
}
```

Not sure how you want to call diff2() and easy(), though.